# serializing LinqToSql generated entities keeping relations and lazy loading

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, serialization, azure, protobuf-net

We have a rather large ASP.NET MVC project using LINQ to SQL which we are in the process of migrating to Windows Azure.

Now, we need to serialize objects for storing in the Azure distributed cache, and setting "*Serialization Mode*" to "*Unidirectional*" in the .dbml file, and thus automatically decorating the generated classes and properties with `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes accordingly, seems to be the recommended way. However, this makes any relationships not yet loaded by LINQ to SQL to be lost when serializing and saved as `null`.

What would be the prefered way of proceeding, taking into account a couple of things:

- As mentioned, it's a rather **large project** with the generated *.designer.cs file being close to 1.5MB
- **Disabling lazy loading** completely would most likely be a big
  **performance hit** due to many deep class relationships.
- **Changing ORM tool** is something we are considering, but doing this at the same time as switching platforms would probably be a bad thing.

If this boils down to somehow manually specifying which objects and relations to serialize accross the whole project; using something like **protobuf-net** for some extra performance gains would probably not be a huge step.

Comment: My opinion: do not use generated entities for serialization/rpc. Build a separate transport model that you control, and that fits the requirements. You are forcing a single model to serve two different use cases, causing trouble in many different places. The amount of work saved by reusing the entity classes is negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, this makes any relationships not yet loaded by LINQ to SQL to be lost when serializing and saved as null.

Yes, this is normal and expected when serializing - you are essentially taking a snapshot of what was available *at that time*, because lazy-loading depends on it being loaded via a data-context. It would be inadviseable for any tool to crawl the entire model looking for things to load, because that could keep going indefinitely, essentially bringing large chunks of unwanted data into play.

Options:

- explicitly fetch (either pre-emptively via "loadwith", or by hitting the appropriate properties) the data you are interested in before serializing
- or, load the data into a **completely separate** DTO model for serialization - in many ways, this is a re-statement of the first, since it will *by necessity* involve iterating over (projecting) the data you want, but it means you are creating the DTO to suit the exact shape you **actually** want to send